# Smooth border of a region ParametricPlot

Tags: numerics, regions, parametric-functions

I have some ugly region plots due to numeric convergence.

Here is the code

```
f1=-(5/3) - (16 (-1 + A^2))/(3 (A + Cosh[Sqrt[2/3] x])^2) + (8 A)/(A + Cosh[Sqrt[2/3] x])
f2= (64 Sinh[Sqrt[2/3] x]^2)/(3 (A + Cosh[Sqrt[2/3] x])^2)
cond = 3/4 ((1 - A) Log[Cosh[x/Sqrt[6]]] + (1 + A) Log[Sinh[x/Sqrt[6]]]) - 3/4 ((1 - A) Log[Cosh[ArcCosh[-A]/2]] + (1 + A) Log[Sinh[ArcCosh[-A]/2]])
ParametricPlot[{ConditionalExpression[f1, 50 < cond < 60], ConditionalExpression[f2, 50 < cond < 60]}, {A, -100, -50}, {x,0.2, 1.5}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{0.92, 1}, {0, 0.006}}, Frame -> True]
```

The result is the picture below

[image]

As you can see there is a lot of noise at the boundaries of the region, which I would like to remove. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Increase the PlotPoints!

```
ParametricPlot[{ConditionalExpression[f1, 50 < cond < 60], 
  ConditionalExpression[f2, 50 < cond < 60]}, {A, -100, -50}, {x, 0.2,
   1.5}, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{0.92, 1}, {0, 0.006}}, 
 Frame -> True, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you a lot. I had no idea such option existed, the manual for ParametricPlot leaves a bit to desire...